# How to sort alphabetically a List<char[]> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I have a list of strings and I was sorting them using:

```
if (SortedList[x].str[p].CompareTo(SortedList[x + 1].str[p]) > 0) //Sort the list
{
    Data aux = SortedList[x];
    SortedList[x] = SortedList[x + 1];
    SortedList[x + 1] = aux;
 }
```

`str` is the list of strings but I had to convert that list to a `List<char[]>` and now I can't use the `str.CompareTo()` method because that is just for strings...

I was thinking about creating a list of strings converting the `char[]` to `string` and the sorting it with the `CompareTo()` method that I was using and then just creating another `List<char[]>` by converting the sorted string list.

Is there a more efficient way to just sort the `List<char[]>`?

Comment: Is it `List<char[]>` or `char[]` or `List<char>`, because right now your wording is ambiguous.

Comment: if you want to sort a list of strings why not just `str.Sort();`?

Comment: Please provide a *full* example including all relevant declarations. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, it is absolutely not clear what kind of problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @TJWolschon it's List<char[]> sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use LINQ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var charList = new List<char[]>();

        // Initialize list of char array
        char[] array1 = { 's', 'a', 'm' };
        char[] array2 = { 's', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h' };
        char[] array3 = { 'c', 'o', 'o', 'l'};

        // Add them
        charList.Add(array1);
        charList.Add(array2);
        charList.Add(array3);

        Console.WriteLine("--Before sorting--");
        foreach (char[] item in charList) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        // Sorting
        charList = charList.OrderBy(a => new string(a)).ToList();


        Console.WriteLine("--After sorting--");
        foreach (char[] item in charList) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--Before sorting--
sam
smith
cool
--After sorting--
cool
sam
smith
```

Test here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wcYSAE

Edit: Although I am not clear based on your question, normally when I have to sort List, I prefer to use what C# has to offer instead of reinventing the wheel. regarding performance, other C# gurus can answer it for us.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going yo use the OrderBy() method.

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement what you said and I'm getting this error:
Argument1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'char*' and it's pointing here:
`OrderBy(a => new string(a)).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Sort? As mentioned by [Aominè](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5862071/aomin%C3%A8)

```
// Declare Sentence Variable
string sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
// Initialize New List of type char
List<char> charList = new List<char>();
// Remove Spaces and Lowercase all Letters and Add to List
charList.AddRange(sentence.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower());
// Sort List<char>()
charList.Sort();
// Output Statements
Console.WriteLine($"Before: {sentence}");
Console.WriteLine($"After: {new string(charList.ToArray())}");
```

Output:

```
Before: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
After: abcdeeefghhijklmnoooopqrrsttuuvwxyz
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is that I have a list of char[] not a list of char, you know? a list of an arrays of chars. The question has been answered, thank you for your time.